# Using Android Studio to switch between pages, error occurs saying "not an enclosing class:MainActivity"

Tags: python, java, android

```
package com.example.multipage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle ;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;


public class Page2 extends Activity {

    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newpage);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnl);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intentMain2Activity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentMain2Activity);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

code does not work, giving error    error: not an enclosing class: MainActivity
Intent intentMain2Activity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);

Answer (score 0):

You need a `context` for the `Intent`. Change the following line:

```
Intent intentMain2Activity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
```

to

```
Intent intentMain2Activity = new Intent(Page2.this, MainActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your fault:

```
 Intent intentMain2Activity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
```

We use the intent object to move from one page to another. but you placed the same pages in the intent object. So use this:

```
Intent intentMain2Activity = new Intent(Page2.this, MainActivity.class);
```

If you want to send data to the page to be passed with the intent object, use:

```
intentMain2Activity.putExtra("object_name", *your object*);
```